# Limit width of flexbox container to viewport width no matter how large the width of flex items are

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a pen here where i have a flexbox container with two children: left and right. I want to keep the container width constrained by viewport width no matter the screen size so that the right div which has exceedingly high width be scrollable as part of the constraint. How do I achieve this?

https://codepen.io/marshall-lee/pen/OJboGjm

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  width: 3000px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can assign a fixed width to left section and use calc function to assign right section width i.e. calc( 100vw - left_section_width).

Comment: @SunnyGoel is there a way without assigning the fixed width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `overflow: auto` to the `.right` parent `div`.

`.right` is overflowing the parent. It's not overflowing itself.

```css
.container > div:last-child {
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  width: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

follow the below code :-

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
}

.left-container{
  background-color:red;
  flex:1;
}

.right-container{
  flex:11;
  overflow-x:auto;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  width: 3000px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-container">left</div>
  <div class="right-container"><div class="right">right</div></div>
</div>
```

it will work as you expected.